# Showing two vertices have same degree under a certain condition

Tags: graph-theory

Let $L$ be the Laplacian matrix of a simple, connected graph, and $\mathcal{P}_j$ the projector into the vertex $v_j$, represented by the appropriate canonical basis vector $(0,...,1,...,0)^T$. Given the positive real parameters $t$ and $\lambda$, consider the functions $$P_j(n,t,\lambda)=v_j^T e^{-it(\lambda L-\mathcal{P}_j)}s, $$ where $s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1,...,1)^T$ is the normalized uniform vector.

My objective is to show that the condition $P_i=P_j$ implies the degrees of the two vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ are the same. Does anyone have any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: (1) Using $t$ for transpose and for time is not a good idea. (2) What’s coordination number?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil You are not wrong, I edited the post. I believe the more familiar English term for coordination number is *degree* of a vertex, so I changed that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take $\lambda=1$ and use $E_j$ for $\mathcal{P}_j$. The $k$-th time derivative of $e^{-it(L-E_j)}s$ at $t=0$ is
\[
(-i(L-E_j))^k s.
\]
Now $(L-E_j)s = -v_j$ (because $Ls=0$) and, noting that $E_j=v_jv_j^T$, we have
\[
(L-E_j)^2s = -(L-E_j)v_j = -Lv_j +v_j.
\]
Therefore
\[
v_j^T(L-E_j)^2s = -v_j^T Lv_j + 1 = - L_{j,j} + 1.
\]
Since $L_{j,j}$ is the degree of vertex $j$, it follows that if $P_i=P_j$, then $i$ and $j$ have the same degree.

[I am curious as to where this problem is coming from?]

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris. Your answer is pretty close to what I was building up to: the big difference is that I was trying to calculate directly $(L-E_j)^k$ (I got stuck there and even asked another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815486/explicitly-evaluating-powers-of-a-sum-of-non-commuting-matrices)). I missed the idea of taking the time derivative! [I am an undergraduate physicist doing some research in quantum computation theory, the problem comes from there :)]

Comment: I'm thinking of a more general version of the problem. Right now we have found a necessary condition for $P_i=P_j$, but I have reasons to conjecture that $P_i=P_j$ if and only if there exists $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(G)$ such that $\sigma(v_i)=v_j$  (which of course implies the two vertices have the same degree). I'm open to ideas for a proof... but of course *not* a complete answer!

Comment: That will fail. Choose your graph to be strongly regular and asymmetric.

Comment: That's bad news. I was guided by the path graph, for which $P_i=P_{n-i+1}$, and of course this is consistent with the action of the path-reversing $\sigma$. Also, $P$ is constant over the symmetric cycle graph, and for every non-central vertex of the wheel or star graphs. However I saw that it fails for Frucht graphs, which are $3-$regular but asymmetric, and yet $P$ is constant. Could it actually just be a sufficient, but not necessary condition?

Comment: I think the answer is that trivially when there is an automorphism all properties of the vertex, including $P$, are carried over to its image. Then, other properties like (strong) regularity may play a role. I was also thinking of studying the distance matrices of these graphs to see if they have something in common...

Comment: @Ugly Duckling: If you want to discuss this further, you can find my email address by googling.